# ODOO Web Service API is not working by using PHP code given in odoo web services API

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am using the following php code to connect odoo web services by using the below link
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html

```
$url = "http://188.166.242.45:8069/";
$db = "test_db";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";

require_once('ripcord-master/ripcord.php');
$info = ripcord::client('http://188.166.242.45:8069/')->start();
list($url, $db, $username, $password) =
  array($info['host'], $info['database'], $info['user'], $info['password']);
```

But this shows the below error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Ripcord_TransportException' with message 'Could not access http://188.166.242.43:8069/' in D:\xampp\htdocs\web_services\ripcord-master\ripcord_client.php:488 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\web_services\ripcord-master\ripcord_client.php(228): Ripcord_Transport_Stream->post('http://188.166....', '<?xml version="...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\web_services\index.php(10): Ripcord_Client->__call('start', Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\web_services\index.php(10): Ripcord_Client->start() #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\web_services\ripcord-master\ripcord_client.php on line 488
```

How can I resolve this???

Comment: did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the link: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html shows the Php code for making the Api call. It uses the ripcord xmlrpc Php library. The example shows the url as: https://demo.odoo.com/start. Your url does not include the /start. Try to use this url: http://188.166.242.45:8069/start. Have you installed the Odoo on port 8069?.

The note below the example says that the ripcord library requires the phpxmlrpc and openssl extensions. It also requires https for the api url